# Custom settings in tests if it's trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, customsetting

I have a trigger with custom settings and test for it. And I have an example how to test it right:

```
@IsTest
void testWithSettings() {
    Example_Settings__c exampleSettings = Settings.getExample();
    // This updates the cached instance, so when the production code gets the settings
    // using Settings.getExample() the production code will see these values
    exampleSettings.Some_Setting_Value__c = 123;
    exampleSettings.Some_Other_Setting_Value__c = 'abc';

    // So now you can call the production code and it will see the values 123 and abc
    ...
}
```

But when I test a trigger helper, I can't actually call the method. I mean, how to do that? How to pass my custom settings from test to the helper's method such as `myMethod(Trigger.new)`? And I don't want to use `SeeAllData` because this is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example was taken from [an answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297418/the-custom-setting-parameter-in-unit-tests-is-null/297424#297424) I gave on a separate question where I explained why you would want to do this.

You can use this pattern successfully in a trigger as well as long as the trigger uses the same mechanism for accessing the (cached) settings instance.

@David Reed's comment that the "proper way of exposing custom settings" is to insert them into the database is flawed due to the existence of the edge case problem I was providing a solution to in this other question, at least if you want to be able to run tests in parallel.

A trigger is quite at liberty to invoke methods on apex classes to which it has access:

```
trigger Abc on MyObject__c (before insert) {
    ExampleSettings__c exampleSettings = Settings.getExample();

    if (exampleSettings.Some_Setting_Value__c == 123) {
        // Do something specific
    }
}
```

Your trigger will be called when a DML operation is applied to an instance of MyObject__c:

```
@IsTest
void testSomething() {
    ExampleSettings__c exampleSettings = Settings.getExample();
    exampleSettings.Some_Setting_Value__c = 456;

    MyObject__c myObject = new MyObject__c(Something_Or_Other__c = 'value');

    // Assuming Settings has been written in much the way I suggested in the other
    // question's answer, the trigger will see Some_Setting_Value__c as 456
    insert myObject;
}
```

If you are saying that this trigger is to be against the custom settings type itself, AFAIK this is not supported anyway.

By the way, you should avoid putting code directly in a trigger but instead have the trigger use a separate object/class (such as a "helper"). In this case you can test the trigger behaviour without having to insert any objects into the database at all (for the most part at least) since you can provide tests directly on the "helper" class itself. A significant help in doing this is to only reference Trigger.old, Trigger.new and the other Trigger properties within the trigger and to pass these values as parameters to your helper's methods.